# How can I create a button (or hotkey) that will automatically connect my bluetooth headset?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-8.1, autohotkey

I have a bluetooth headset that I would like to be able to quickly switch between connection from my laptop(running windows 8) to my phone. I downloaded autohotkey to help me make a hotkey that would connect to my bluetooth headset, but I was only able to make a hotkey that would open the bluetooth control panel for my specific headset, which is not what I was trying to accomplish. What I am trying to accomplish is a hotkey that would immediately connect my headset when typed.

The code I used in autohotkey, to open the bluetooth control panel(by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) is:

```
^!b:: run "C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\BTWUIExt.exe"  /deviceAddr=445ef3aa5294
```

this code won't work for you as the numbers and letters on the end are a uniqe idendifier for my specific headset.  You can find your unique id by opening bluetooth in the control panel and right clicking your headset, selecting properties, clicking the bluetooth tab (remove the dots and colons).

Comment: Please provide your code and more detailed information. What steps are necessary to connect your headset, in contrast to opening it in the control panel?

Comment: I added the code and an explanation of how to make it work for you.

Comment: What steps are necessary to connect your headset, in contrast to just opening it in the control panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked to connect the first bluetooth device in the list (Windows 10)

```
#SingleInstance,force
;https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/83571-autohotkey-connect-to-bluetooth/
^F1::
Run, bthprops.cpl
Sleep, 2000
Send, {tab}{tab}{enter}{tab}{enter}
Sleep, 200
Send,!{Tab}
return
```

Comment: Not very robust, seeing as the order of the list can change. That being said, yours is easy to fix, and the script I had is now long gone, so I may as well mark yours as the answer.

Comment: I have only one device works flawlessly with minor modifications. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

There is very little information to give exact solution. But from given information I can say:

1. You can automate GUI with AutoHotkey so that script will go to the
   place where `unique id` is located. In fact, AutoHotkey allows any
   GUI automation (conventional or non conventional GUI).
2. If the `unique id` is there as a text and you can copy it, then it
   also can be automated by several ways. If `unique id` cant be coped
   and is as image, then it is slightly complicated and you need to use some OCR
   techniques. In that case you need to make screenshot of that region
   and use some OCR script getting text out of it. Or with AutoHotkey pass image to OCR software and get text from it.
3. After you have text, you can manipulate it the way you like. Most powerfull solution
   is Regular Expressions which are supported by AutoHotkey.
4. When `unique id` is ready to use, you can use it in Run
   command this way:

   ^!b:: run "C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\BTWUIExt.exe"  %MyUnicIDVariable%

Comment: Apparently my code already worked, but thanks for the answer. I might look into it.

Comment: @vasili  I don't understand You can automate GUI with AutoHotkey so that script will go to the place where unique id is located. please provide more details how to do it. (are you talking about getting some GUI infos using the windows spy, or another tool? )

Comment: @JinSnow You can navigate to any place in GUI using conventional or non conventional GUI automation methods. For conmands for GUI navigation/automation look at official documentation "Mouse and keyboard section", for ImageSearch command and other commands that allow getting pixel info. To get information from GUI control use https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm command (that will give us simmilar and in some cases more info than winspy and similar tools.).

Comment: @vasili111 Thanks I did not know about ControlGet! By chance is there an app/tool like winspy that would show directly the control infos (rather than coding to get them)? (I'm on windows10)

Comment: @JinSnow AutoHotkey has "Active Window Info (Window Spy)" software bundled. It is in Autohotkey start menu folder.

Comment: @vasili111 but windows spy, doesn't show the control (eg. in windows settings, it doesn't show anything interesting (eg. button name and it's state) when I hovering the Bluetooth ON/OFF button)

Comment: @JinSnow In that case, try a different method of extracting the information that you need. AutoHotkey allows different methods of extraction of information. For example, you can read information from memory with classMemory (https://github.com/ahkscript/awesome-AutoHotkey#memory)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the code I have works on its own. If I just wait for about 10 seconds after typing out the hotkey, the headphones connect, and the control panel that opened automatically closes. Quite convenient actually as I didn't expect it to connect or to auto-close the window.

Thanks for the effort anyway!

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add the working code and then accept it? Just for the sake of completeness and so that others see what your solution is at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [Broadcom Bluetooth 4.0 Driver for Windows 8.1 ] LINK=>> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkTYP.png) ! 
At least works fine on my HP-EliteBook-8570p with stereo "BlueDio 99B" headset. After switching the headset ON the Windows connect the device automatically, and switch Audio-Stream into new-attached device. Optimal!
 PS - Unfortunately it is still the Problem with Windows 8.1 + Skype( MIC-Problem) :( Windows 8 is the first OS, than not support Skype at all! ;)

[image: Connected BT Headset]
[image: AudioIN]
[image: AudioOUT]